# ROS2: Can subscribe to String, but not Twist, "no overloaded function"

Tags: ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the example subscriber found in the official ROS2 tutorials, I was able to create a subscriber that listened for String messages.  I then tried to simply change it to listen to Twist messages, and I get a ton of errors,  After doing some research, it appears to have something to do with the arguments in my callback function.  I tried the solutions from these two sources, but nothing worked!
https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/583

https://answers.ros.org/question/308386/ros2-add-arguments-to-callback/

Ignoring the silly class name and motor controller stuff, here is my cpp src file:

```
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/twist.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "ctre/Phoenix.h"
#include "ctre/phoenix/platform/Platform.h"
#include "ctre/phoenix/platform/can/PlatformCAN.h"
#include "ctre/phoenix/unmanaged/Unmanaged.h"
#include <string>
#include "rclcpp/node.hpp"
#include "ctre/phoenix/MotorControl/ControlMode.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace ctre::phoenix;
using namespace ctre::phoenix::platform;
using namespace ctre::phoenix::motorcontrol;
using namespace ctre::phoenix::motorcontrol::can;

using std::placeholders::_1;

class Hello : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    Hello() : Node("pub_hello")
    {

      rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>::SharedPtr subscriber;

      subscriber = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>(
        "topic", 10, std::bind(&Hello::topic_callback, this, _1));
      
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Node Running");

    }

    void topic_callback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Twist) const
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  TalonSRX talon = 1;
  auto node = std::make_shared<Hello>();

    ctre::phoenix::platform::can::SetCANInterface("can0");

  talon.Set(ControlMode::Velocity, 0);

  while(rclcpp::ok())
  {
    rclcpp::spin(node);
  }
  
  rclcpp::shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

And the large amount of errors that follow:

```
  hello.cpp
C:\dev\ros2_foxy\include\rclcpp/subscription_factory.hpp(97): error C2672: 'rclcpp::AnySubscriptionCallback<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT>::set': no matching overloaded function found [C:\dev\colcon_ws\build\lunabotics2021\hello.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              CallbackMessageT=geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,
              AllocatorT=std::allocator<void>
          ]
  C:\dev\ros2_foxy\include\rclcpp/create_subscription.hpp(143): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'rclcpp::SubscriptionFactory rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<MessageT,_Ty,std::allocator<void>,CallbackMessageT,rclcpp::Subscription<CallbackMessageT,std::allocator<void>,rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<MessageT,AllocatorT>>,rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<MessageT,AllocatorT>>(CallbackT &&,const rclcpp::SubscriptionOptionsWithAllocator<std::allocator<void>> &,std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<MessageT,AllocatorT>>,std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::topic_statistics::SubscriptionTopicStatistics<CallbackMessageT>>)' being compiled
          with
          [
              MessageT=geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,
              _Ty=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Hello::* )(geometry_msgs::msg::Twist) const,Hello *,const std::_Ph<1> &>,
              CallbackMessageT=geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,
              AllocatorT=std::allocator<void>,
              CallbackT=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Hello::* )(geometry_msgs::msg::Twist) const,Hello *,const std::_Ph<1> &>
          ]
  c:\dev\ros2_foxy\include\rclcpp\node_impl.hpp(104): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,std::allocator<void>,rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT>>> rclcpp::create_subscription<MessageT,_Ty,std::allocator<void>,geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void>>,rclcpp::Subscription<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT,rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<MessageT,AllocatorT>>,rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<MessageT,AllocatorT>,rclcpp::Node&>(NodeT,const std::string &,const rclcpp::QoS &,CallbackT &&,const rclcpp::SubscriptionOptionsWithAllocator<std::allocator<void>> &,std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<MessageT,AllocatorT>>)' being compiled
          with
          [
              CallbackMessageT=geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,
              AllocatorT=std::allocator<void>,
              MessageT=geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,
              _Ty=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Hello::* )(geometry_msgs::msg::Twist) const,Hello *,const std::_Ph<1> &>,
              NodeT=rclcpp::Node &,
              CallbackT=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Hello::* )(geometry_msgs::msg::Twist) const,Hello *,const std::_Ph<1> &>
          ]
  C:\dev\colcon_ws\src\lunabotics2021\src\hello.cpp(28): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,std::allocator<void>,rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT>>> rclcpp::Node::create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Hello::* )(geometry_msgs::msg::Twist) const,Hello *,const std::_Ph<1> &>,std::allocator<void>,geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void>>,rclcpp::Subscription<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT,rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT>>,rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT>>(const std::string &,const rclcpp::QoS &,CallbackT &&,const rclcpp::SubscriptionOptionsWithAllocator<std::allocator<void>> &,std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT>>)' being compiled
          with
          [
              CallbackMessageT=geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,
              AllocatorT=std::allocator<void>,
              CallbackT=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Hello::* )(geometry_msgs::msg::Twist) const,Hello *,const std::_Ph<1> &>
          ]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\chrono(871): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::milli>' being compiled
C:\dev\ros2_foxy\include\rclcpp/subscription_factory.hpp(97): error C2783: 'void rclcpp::AnySubscriptionCallback<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT>::set(CallbackT)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal' [C:\dev\colcon_ws\build\lunabotics2021\hello.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              CallbackMessageT=geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,
              AllocatorT=std::allocator<void>
          ]
  C:\dev\ros2_foxy\include\rclcpp/any_subscription_callback.hpp(83): note: see declaration of 'rclcpp::AnySubscriptionCallback<CallbackMessageT,AllocatorT>::set'
          with
          [
              CallbackMessageT=geometry_msgs::msg::Twist,
              AllocatorT=std::allocator<void>
          ]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363645/ros2:-can-subscribe-to-string,-but-not-twist,-%22no-overloaded-function%22/) by [JoelB](https://answers.ros.org/users/60849/joelb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason is a wrong argument type in callback. Add SharedPtr

```
void topic_callback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Twist::SharedPtr) const
```

---

Originally posted by [rrrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/59836/rrrand/) with karma: 63 on 2020-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoelB](https://answers.ros.org/users/60849/joelb/) on 2020-10-21**:
That was it!  I had also forgotten to add geometry_msg to the cmakeLists.  Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-08-20**:
If it worked, please press the grey check button so others can find their similar case fixed :)